# How does the Detect Magic spell see any creature that knows at least one cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, cantrips

The *detect magic* spell states (emphasis mine):

> you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around *any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic*

And the definition of a cantrip in the PH is (emphasis mine):

> A cantrip i s a spell that can be cast at will [...]. Repeated practice has fixed the spell in the caster's mind *and infused the caster with the magic* needed to produce the effect over and over.

**Is a visible creature that knows and can cast at least one cantrip detected as "bearing magic" by the spell *detect magic*?**

I am aware that the spell cannot detect the ability to cast spells in creatures that prepare / learn spells of 1st level or higher. The description of cantrips is the only one that speaks about the caster *being infused with magic*.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. Let us know if that question doesn't answer your question, and clarify why so we can reopen it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I've already read that question and the answers in there, but it only talks about prepared / known spells, and cantrips aside, none of those spellcasting traits describe the caster as "being infused with the magic needed for it". The only common part is the spell being fixed in the caster's mind, which is clear enough and not pertinent for _detect magic_.

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying *it is* the same question, but the answers there are not satisfying?

Comment: It is similar. As I've edited, only cantrips have that specific different description.

Comment: I see now. To me, it looks like we've definitely got a duplicate question here, but you're right, the answers to the target should probably address cantrips better. The thing to do here is to leave comments with your concerns there, *or* if you're feeling frisky, bounty that question and mention in the bounty description the rule you think needs to be addressed in answers.

Comment: I'm not sure how a wizard being "infused with the magic needed" is different from a dragon being "naturally magical" with respect to its breath weapon. Does that part of the prior answer not address the concern?